# UITableView has UIScrollView in Cell cannot scroll in ios simulator 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I coding a IOS app. A view in app has a UITableView with UIScrollView in Cell. I added some UIView to UIScrollView and make scroll.

When I run it on IOS Simulator 8.3 (iphone 6). The table cannot scroll up and down. So I make UIScrollView in Cell cannot scroll, and the table can scroll.
When i run it on device (Iphone 6 8.3 - real) and IOS Simulator 7.1 (iphone 5s), it run normal (UIScrollView in Cell and UITableView can scroll).

Unfortunately, My customer use a Iphone 6, but It cannot scroll same as my IOS Simulator 8.3 (iphone 6).

Have anyway to fix it?

Thank a lot, sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score -1):

You should only add one child to the UIScrollView, and you will have to set the constraints for it like that:

```
LeadingSpaceToContainer = 0
TrailingSpaceToContainer = 0
TopSpaceToContainer = 0
BottomSpaceToContainer = 0
EqualWidths between UIScrollView and child UIView
Static height for child UIView
```

Only then the UIScrollView is really scrollable (and of course if the child UIView's height is greater than the UIScrollView's height)